# I am getting Reference Error: variable is not defined error when I am trying to pass variable from one function to another in JavaScript ( postman)

Tags: javascript, postman

I am getting Reference Error: variable is not defined error when I am trying  to pass variable from one function to another in JavaScript ( postman)

Error : ReferenceError: isinDB is not defined

```
    //Verify ISIN with DB API
    pm.test("Row : " + i + "-"+dataArr[1] + ":Verify symbol isin with DB API", function () {
        console.log("isin " + dataArr[6]);
        //Getting isin from DB API
        pm.sendRequest("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080/ords/unidata/symbol/symbol/" + dataArr[1], function  (err, response ) {
            var resBoday = response.json()
            var isinDB = resBoday.items[0].isin_code;
            console.log("isinDB "+isinDB);
            
        });
        
        pm.expect(dataArr[6]).is.to.equals(isinDB);
    });
```

Comment: ```Java``` and ```Javascript``` are totally different. Just like ```car``` and ```carpet```. So please change your tag to ```Javascript``` instead of ```Java```.

Answer (score 0):

`isinDB` is declared in the function callback, so it is not defined in the outer scope. Even if you declare it in the outer scope, it will not be available till the callback with `response` is called. Maybe you can test in callback, this way?

```js
    //Verify ISIN with DB API
    pm.test("Row : " + i + "-"+dataArr[1] + ":Verify symbol isin with DB API", function () {
        console.log("isin " + dataArr[6]);
        //Getting isin from DB API
        pm.sendRequest("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080/ords/unidata/symbol/symbol/" + dataArr[1], function  (err, response ) {
            var resBoday = response.json()
            var isinDB = resBoday.items[0].isin_code;
            console.log("isinDB "+isinDB);
            pm.expect(dataArr[6]).is.to.equals(isinDB);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed from below code .. thanks for the support

```
    //Verify ISIN with DB API
    pm.test("Row : " + i + " - " + dataArr[1] + " :  Verify symbol isin with DB API", function () {
        var isinC = dataArr[6];
        console.log("isin " + dataArr[6]);
        //Getting isin from DB API
        pm.sendRequest("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080/ords/unidata/symbol/symbol/" + dataArr[1], function (err, response) {
            var resBoday = response.json()
            var isinDB = resBoday.items[0].isin_code;
            console.log("isinDB " + isinDB);
            //pm.expect(dataArr[6]).is.to.equals(isinDB);
            console.log("test" + isinC);
            pm.expect(isinC).is.to.equals(isinDB);


        });

    });
```